# What program will overwrite /etc/network/interface on boot?

Tags: networking, live-cd

I'm making a custom Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 Live CD. Here is what I did:

- `debootstrap` a folder
- install `casper` package (and some other packages needed) in chroot
- put the folder into squashfs
- set up GRUB2 in ISO to boot from squashfs

Now the OS is working, but `/etc/network/interface` is overwritten (i.e. not the same version as what I put into squashfs) every boot. What program is overwriting it?

NetworkManager is not installed. systemd-networkd is set to disabled.

Comment: Excellent question... I can't believe this still happens in Ubuntu 18. Seriously, the distros need to be better screened for these rogue utilities that infinitely complicate basic system administration. Some of them kick in, like, 1 every 10 boots. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: casper will wipe network configuration unless explicitly set `ip=frommedia` in kernel commandline.

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/systemback/+question/261587